# Is color monitor profiling enough when using color-management-aware software?

Tags: colors, color-profiles

I'm researching color management out of interest and want to understand how the various parts (monitor, gamma loader, display profile) fit together.
Am I right, that if I accept the native whitepoint of my monitor and I am using color-management aware software (i. e. converts its colors into monitor profile), I only need to profile (not calibrate) my monitor? Because a monitor profile already contains either matrix/TRC values or a LUT? And I don't need to calibrate my monitor?

(I see the point that when using a gamma loader to load vcgt into video card LUT I also get "correct" gamma e.g. in Windows GUI and non-color-management-aware software. And that I have to use vcgt to adjust whitepoint, if I don't want to change it on my monitor's OSD controls.)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you're asking if having a color profile for your monitor (e.g., downloading the one for your display) makes color profiling unnecessary?  If that is your question:

The color response of a monitor changes over time, something that calibration can account for (but a profile may not).  A good colorimeter will also measure ambient light and adjust the monitor accordingly.  A fixed color profile (made for all monitors of the same model) can't account for variations or ambient light.

If you want professional results, I highly recommend a colorimeter/calibration.

Comment: Not exactly. I have a colorimeter, and I use the profile created with a colorimeter. My question is if the profile needs to have a vcgt tag, which a gamma loader or the OS loads into the video card LUT.